# How would an individual dword of an array in intel x86(little endian) assembly be stored for value 5?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, endianness, dword

I am currently a university student and my professor zoomed in while recording the lecture so I couldn't see what he was writing. I'm not sure how for example a "DWORD 5" would be stored say for example starting at location 2000:

**I was thinking**

2000: 00000101

2001: 00000000

2002: 00000000

2003: 00000000

**but I'm not sure if it could be.**

2000: 00000000

2001: 00000000

2002: 00000000

2003: 00000101

I would appreciate it if someone could explain which one is correct.

Comment: It depends on the architecture you are programming for.  On x86, a *little endian* architecture, the former is correct.  On *big endian* architectures like M68k, the latter is correct.  Some architectures have configurable endianess (e.g. ARM, PPC, MIPS).

Comment: you can try this yourself with an assembler, e.g. put `dd 5` in a file called `foo.asm` and run `nasm foo.asm -l/dev/stdout` to write a "listing" to stdout, with the bytes hex-dumped in memory order.  (And create `foo.bin` which you could also hexdump).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x86 is little-endian, and ["[a] little-endian system, stores the least-significant byte at the smallest address"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

So, the first one.